# Extract phone numbers from Gmail email body

Tags: regex, email, gmail, preg-match

Is there a good sollution to get real phone numbers from Gmail email body?
I tried to get the emails via IMAP but the html result not really parseable.

My code:

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$emails,1);
```

The body result is:

example 1:

```
 bla-bla-bla
 <strong>TEXT</strong>
 " : +22545091040"
 <br />
 bla-bla-bla
```

example 2:

```
bla-bla-bla
<strong>TEXT</strong>
" : 0980653935 France"
<br />
bla-bla-bla
```

All email have the following structure:

```
 Bonjour,<br><br>Voici le numéro de téléphone de <strong>*NAME*</strong> : *INPUT1 DATA*<br>
 <br>Son adresse email est la suivante : *INPUT2 DATA*<br>
```

Is there a regex or some different way to extract this phone numbers form the email body?

Thank you!

Comment: International phone numbers come in various formats and even change periodically. Unless you know exactly where they are in the body... anything tried so far?

Comment: I added the complete email structure to my question.

Comment: Yes any other caracters can be found in the phone number part. Sometimes there are strings and useless characters like: O147659990

Comment: No, I mean, like can the _actual_ phone number contain other characters?

Comment: Any luck with the regex?

Comment: Your first sollution doesnt work for me, but with small modification on the second one and on my script, it seems to be working. `preg_match_all("~[0-9\-\(\)' ']+~", $message, $aMatches); ... if(strlen($data) > 5){ ...`, Thank you!

Comment: So there _can_ be other characters `()-0 ` in the phone number? I could have put it in the regex if you said so :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe try using `preg_match` on the email body:

```
preg_match('~[0-9]+(?=[^"]+"<)~', $body, $number);
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/oW9cK0).

This regex is relying on the fact that there are quotes in the part containing the phone number (otherwise, you might be getting numbers occurring earlier in the email body). If there can be no numbers before it, you can simply use:

```
preg_match('~[0-9]+~', $body, $number);
```

Comment: Nice! Only small modification needed: `preg_match_all("~[0-9\-\(\)' ']+~", $message, $aMatches); ... if(strlen($data) > 5){ ...`

Comment: @Robert Oh and I forgot to mention, you can make the regex a little bit shorter by using `~[0-9()' -]+~` (You don't need to escape metacharacters in character classes). Note that it will match numbers, single quotes, spaces, parentheses and dashes.